# Update Items in MS Dynamics through API

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I am new to MS Dynamics Business Central and I am building an integration for a custom build ECommerce website to MS Dynamics for inventory management and other operations work.

I can run multiple APIs to get company information, get items but whenever I try to update the items, I keep getting an error of "Another user has already changed the record". I am using a If-Match tag as requested but may be my e-tag is not correct. Can you please check and see what is the issue.

The Etag value is

```
"@odata.etag": "W/\"JzE5OzI1NzMyMzIyMjcyOTQ3OTQ4MzExOzAwOyc=\"",
```

The curl statement to update the item is

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/Development/api/v2.0/companies(CompanyNumber)/items(ItemNumber)' \
--header 'If-Match: W/"JzE5OzY1NDk0OTA1NDg2NTk1MDUwODExOzAwOyc="' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--data '{
    "inventory":15
}'
```

I keep getting error that
"message": "Another user has already changed the record.  CorrelationId:  081aa824-be35-4284-9c69-1ea39f8a8ce1."

I feel like the issue is with ETag value where I removed some characters. Can someone please help and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to the awesome community of MSDyn365BC!

From what I can see, you did everything correctly at first sight. You removed the backslashes from the ETag and added the **If-Match** key to the Header of your HTTP request with the slightly modified ETag as it's value. This is correct. The only problem is that the ETags are different. This is the problem as you have to provide the current ETag of the resource as the value of the If-Match key.

To get things started for prototyping purposes, you could use: **" If-Match: * "**

You keep getting the HTTP status code 409 if the ETag does not match the current ETag of the resource you are requesting to use.

Without going into too much detail, everytime someone uses (POST/PUT) this record, the state of the resource changes and so does the ETag. Therefor you need to provide the new ETag for every new HTTP request you send for the specific resource.

For example:

1. GET the resource A and save the ETag "123"
2. PUT the resource A and provide the ETag "123". Success: in the response you notice the ETag changed to "987".
3. PUT the resource A and provide the ETag "123". Failed: results in the HTTP 409 Request_EntityChanged "Another user has already changed the record."
4. PUT the resource A and provide the ETag "987". Success: in the resource you notice the ETag changed to "456".

In your question, there is a difference between the ETag of the resource and the ETag you specify in the header. If your ETag value is

`"@odata.etag": "W/\"JzE5OzI1NzMyMzIyMjcyOTQ3OTQ4MzExOzAwOyc=\""`

then the value of the If-Match key in the header of your HTTP request must provide this value:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/Development/api/v2.0/companies(CompanyNumber)/items(ItemNumber)' \
--header 'If-Match: W/"JzE5OzI1NzMyMzIyMjcyOTQ3OTQ4MzExOzAwOyc="' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--data '{
    "inventory":15
}'
```

I hope this helps to solve the problem.

Additional links:

- ETag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-odata/c4d715eb-10f6-47fa-9ccc-2ebf926558a6
- If-Match: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-odata/c3569037-0557-4769-8f75-a91ffcd7b05b